# Detect a shake in iOS Safari with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, cocoa-touch, ios, mobile-safari

How can I utilize the new MobileSafari device motion APIs to capture a "shake" event?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

See this awesome blog post: http://www.jeffreyharrell.com/blog/2010/11/creating-a-shake-event-in-mobile-safari/

Which illustrates this example:

```
if (typeof window.DeviceMotionEvent != 'undefined') {
    // Shake sensitivity (a lower number is more)
    var sensitivity = 20;

    // Position variables
    var x1 = 0, y1 = 0, z1 = 0, x2 = 0, y2 = 0, z2 = 0;

    // Listen to motion events and update the position
    window.addEventListener('devicemotion', function (e) {
        x1 = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.x;
        y1 = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.y;
        z1 = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.z;
    }, false);

    // Periodically check the position and fire
    // if the change is greater than the sensitivity
    setInterval(function () {
        var change = Math.abs(x1-x2+y1-y2+z1-z2);

        if (change > sensitivity) {
            alert('Shake!');
        }

        // Update new position
        x2 = x1;
        y2 = y1;
        z2 = z1;
    }, 150);
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for adding the code extract. Should be helpful!

Comment: Just a warning: accelerationIncludingGravity will never have all three components zero. If gravity is acting directly on one axis, that axis will have a value of 9.81. Also, why not check for shakes during the event instead of in an interval?

Comment: @Jacob Relkin I realised that on my iPhone 4S the alert occures TWICE after single shake. WHY?

Comment: @andi The only change I had was to get rid of the interval, instead putting the code in the event handler. Thinking now, that might not work as well since the change could appear slower if many events are used. As for double alerts: There is a change when you start shaking and when you stop, so you will get an alert for each.

Comment: The linked blog post has since been removed. Is it viewable somewhere else or is there a similar article I could read?

Comment: Requires permissions in iOS 13+, see https://dev.to/li/how-to-requestpermission-for-devicemotion-and-deviceorientation-events-in-ios-13-46g2